# Inequality involving harmonic functions over the ball and half ball

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-functions

Let $B\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a unit ball. Let $B^+:=B\cap \{x_2\geq 0\}$ where we set $x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$. Let $\omega\in C^1(\partial B)$ be given such that $|\nabla \omega|>0$ for all $x\in\partial B$. We consider the following two equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u_1=0& \text{ if }x\in B\\
u_1=\omega&\text{ if }x\in\partial B
\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u_2=0& \text{ if }x\in B^+\\
u_2=\omega&\text{ if }x\in(\partial B)\cap \{x_2\geq 0\}\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial \nu}u_2=0&\text{ if }x\in B\cap \{x_2=0\}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\nu$ is the outer normal vector at $B\cap \{x_2=0\}$.

My question: would it be possible to prove that 
$$
\int_{B^+}|\nabla u_2|^2dx<\int_{B^+}|\nabla u_1|^2dx
$$
with "$<$" but not "$=$"?

I think the condition $|\nabla \omega|>0$ for all $x\in\partial B$ is the key, but I don't know how to use it...

Of course, if $\omega\equiv c$ for some constant $C$, then the above strict inequality does not hold.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true. First of all, the nonstrict inequality
$$\int_{B^+}|\nabla u_2|^2dx \le \int_{B^+}|\nabla u_1|^2dx \tag{1}$$
holds because $u_2$ minimizes the Dirichlet integral (the LHS of (1)) on the linear space of all functions with boundary value $\omega$ on $\partial B\cap \{x_2\ge 0\}$, and no condition on $B\cap \{x_2=0\}$. (I.e., when a part of the boundary is free of condition, the minimizer satisfies the Neumann condition there: this can be proved by perturbing its boundary values, and in any case is standard.)

If equality holds in (1), then $u_1$ also has zero normal derivative on the boundary (so, $u_2=u_1$). Then the function $\tilde u(x_1,x_2)=u_1(x_1,|x_2|)$ is also harmonic in $B$, which implies $\tilde u=u_1$ in $B$. Therefore, the boundary values $\omega$ are symmetric with respect to the plane $x_2=0$. But this implies that the derivative of $\omega$ vanishes at the points $(\pm 1,0)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! but should it be $u_2$ but not $w$ at the second line of second pargraph?

Comment: I meant $u_1$ there

Comment: One more question. If I have the derivative of $\omega$ vanishes at the points $(\pm 1,0)$, then the equality will be hold, right?

Comment: No. Equality holds iff $\omega$ is even wrt $y$.